# Problems with -moz-box-align: center

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, centering, alignment

I am aligning the text of a paragraph in the middle of a box (to be centered between the top and the bottom) while the text is aligned to the right. This can be achieved with the new **display: box** and some other CSS3 properties.

Does anybody have an idea why **-moz-box-align: center** doesn't work like the -webkit one? This example looks as expected in Chrome but not in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/GBrRK/7/
Any idea is appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `display: box` is not CSS3 - that was replaced with `display: flexbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I found your solution. Delete "float: left;". http://jsfiddle.net/GBrRK/39/

That's some unusual behaviour.